# Has the 'href' behavior of the 'a' tag changed in chrome version 84?

Tags: html, google-chrome

After the Chrome 84 version is released, my webpage works differently from the previous ones and uploads this posting.

This is a code that simply reproduces my issue.

```html
<html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>href issue</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function clickMybutton() {
                console.log("click");
                for (var __i=0; __i < 1000; i++) {
                   $("ul.test").append("<li><div><span>test123</span></div></li>")
                }
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            div {
            display: block;
            }
        </style>
        <div>
            <div>
                <ul class="test">
                    <li>
                        <div><span>test</span></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><span>test</span></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><span>test</span></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#" onclick="clickMybutton()">
                <span>
                ABCD!!
                </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when clicking the 'ABCD!!' until scrolling occur

84 version: fix the scroll location 'ABCD!!'
prev version: not fix scroll location ('ABCD!!' looks like the tag is one line down.)

what happen in chrome 84 version ??

Comment: What mean by `fix the scroll location`?

Comment: You should handle the click event and call `e.preventDefault()` or at least `return false` to prevent default actions from occurring on click.

Comment: yes. Brad. i also solve this problem preventDefault. thanks
The fundamental question is whether there are official documents or announcements about these changes, and changes within the browser.

Comment: change some code href='#!' => href='#', in additional test.... preventDefault can't solve my issue :(

in case of apply preventDefault() like below
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
    });

when click the 'ABCD!!' scoll move bottom..

in case of not apply preventDefault scroll move top of the page

Comment: I solved this problem and also found the cause of the problem. Related links.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1102229